# Browser extension that sends a full page capture of a website to Pinterest

Tags: web-browser, screenshot, sharing, pinterest

I use Chrome, and found [Page2Images Pin Full Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page2images-pin-full-page/gdoimlckmnoomjdlhdbdbombjlbchffe/related?hl=en-GB).

Works great, except that the image captured was so small that I can't read the text, and some text and layout are screwed.

Anyone came across any better extensions? Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Safari has an extension 'Friend + Me' that does the following: The best way to share great content to Google+, Twitter, Facebook, Tumblr, LinkedIn, and Pinterest from anywhere on the web.  I don't know if it does the complete web page. I just saw the extension today.

Answer (score 0):

I use Chrome's [GoFullPage extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gofullpage-full-page-scre/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl) all the time. I haven't yet seen it reduce the picture quality. It doesn't send the image to Pinterest, but you can download the image and then post it on Pinterest.